# Error while using rails_admin with rails5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to use rails_admin with rails5 application. rails_admin 0.8.1 didn't work because

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":   In
>   snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
>       rails (= 5.0.0.beta1)
>
> In Gemfile:
>       rails (< 5.1, >= 5.0.0.beta1)
>
> ```
> rails_admin was resolved to 0.8.1, which depends on
>   rails (~> 4.0)
> ```

Then I tried using the latest code from github by using

> gem 'rails_admin', git: 'https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git'

Now I am getting conflicting rack dependicies.

> In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
>       rack (= 2.0.0.alpha)
>
> In Gemfile:
>       rails (< 5.1, >= 5.0.0.beta1) was resolved to 5.0.0.beta1, which depends on
>         actionmailer (= 5.0.0.beta1) was resolved to 5.0.0.beta1, which depends on
>           actionpack (= 5.0.0.beta1) was resolved to 5.0.0.beta1, which depends on
>             rack (~> 2.x)
>
> ```
> rails_admin was resolved to 0.8.1, which depends on
>   rack-pjax (~> 0.7) was resolved to 0.7.0, which depends on
>     rack (~> 1.3)
>
> rails (< 5.1, >= 5.0.0.beta1) was resolved to 5.0.0.beta1, which depends on
>   sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
>     sprockets (>= 3.0.0) was resolved to 3.5.2, which depends on
>       rack (< 3, > 1)
>
> devise was resolved to 4.0.0.pre.dev, which depends on
>   warden (~> 1.2.3) was resolved to 1.2.4, which depends on
>     rack (>= 1.0)
>
> devise was resolved to 4.0.0.pre.dev, which depends on
>   warden (~> 1.2.3) was resolved to 1.2.4, which depends on
>     rack (>= 1.0)
> ```

Is it too early to start using rails5? Should I go back to rails4.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that RA has Rails5 gemfile https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/gemfiles/rails_5.0.gemfile.  I would try upgrading to all gems mentioned in that file.

Comment: Did it work for you?  I would be curious to know how upgrade went.  I am also looking at Rails 5.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by doing:

```
gem 'rails_admin', github: 'sferik/rails_admin'
gem 'rack-pjax', github: 'afcapel/rack-pjax'
gem 'remotipart', github: 'mshibuya/remotipart', ref: '3a6acb3'
```

see [this article](http://blog.endpoint.com/2016/05/gem-dependency-issues-with-rails-5-beta.html)